# Access the imageView being clicked

Tags: javafx-8

I am making a game in javaFX. The game has lots of tiles. Whenever a tile is clicked , I want to do some visual change on that tile.

What I did was that I created imageViews as tiles. Then I made methods on Clicked,onDragged ,....etc.

```
THIS IS ONE TILE. I WANT REFERENCE TO THIS IN MY Controller.java

<ImageView  fitHeight="117.0" fitWidth="936.0" layoutX="492.0" layoutY="767.0" onMouseClicked="#upgradeBrick" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
      <effect>
        <InnerShadow choke="0.5" height="30.0" radius="14.5" width="30.0" />
      </effect>
      <image>
        <Image url="@../exitGameIcon.png" />
      </image>
    </ImageView>
```

Now I am struck at how to get reference to "that" imageView object.
Basically I want to have reference to that imageView object in my controller.java file.

Comment: Use `fx:id` attribute in your FXML file and `@FXML` annotation in `Controller.java`. Refer to [Introduction to FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html)

Comment: Alternatively declare `upgradeBrick` with a `MouseEvent` parameter; this allows you to get the `ImageView` via `event.getSource()` (Even though the return type of that method is `Object`, so you'll probably need a cast.)

Comment: @fabian This did work , because onMouseClicked actually had a parameters MouseEvent and I got source from it. Thank you!!!!